# OAuth authorization flow for private API with Microsoft AD

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization

Our company is using Microsoft AD for user management and authentication, also the authorization is done using the AD groups/roles. In the most 3rd party applications the users can authenticate with their AD accounts.
Now we are developing new applications, which should use an internal API. Therefor we created a new enterprise app in our Microsoft tenant and defined a couple of roles.
On the client side it is the normal flow - users authenticate with their accounts and the client receives the access token it should send to the API. And here is the point where I am not sure what is the best way to implement it.
Since all the users already exist in the AD, there is no need to only use access token to get the user identifier and create/link the user in the internal database - I want to use the AD users and to be able to verify the roles and use them in the services behind the API gateway "as is". But the roles are not stored in the access token, so I assume, I have to request them from Microsoft separately. But also I do not want to request them every time a user sends a request to my API and want to rely on the token the cliends sends to me and which I can verify.

So what is the best way to implement it? Should I create a new Bearer JWT in our own auth service, containing all information I need, and provide it to the client, so that it sends it to me every time? Should client use this token for authorizing the user as well? But it also can request the IDToken from Microsoft? Would our internal token replace IDToken and Access Token? Or should we just use IDToken for requests to the API?
Creating an own token looks like an overhead to me, since we only work with AD users but I also don't want to use IDToken for authorization in the API.

Comment: It seems that you wanna your new application can validate the user's role in the authentication, maybe you can refer to this section. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles#support-in-aspnet-core-middleware-libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an OAuth architecture your apps (primarily APIs) accept tokens from the Authorization Server (Azure AD in your case). You then use these tokens to authorize requests for data based on [Scopes](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) and [Claims](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/). Avoid issuing your own tokens and use AS tokens consistently. It feels like you then need to deal with `domain specific claims`, which is tricky, and these are the main concerns:

**Option 1: Custom Claims in JWT Access Tokens**

This requires Azure AD to reach out to your internal API at the time of token issuance. This is the preferred option but it may not be supported - or possible - depending on the provider and hosting infrastructure.

**Option 2: Custom Claims via Lookup**

Here is some [example C# code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/ClaimsCachingAuthorizer.cs#L35) that shows a technique where you form a custom claims principal in the target API. The extra claims are looked up (typically from a database) when the access token is first received, then cached for future requests with the same access token. It is not ideal but I have had to use it in the past due to vendor limitations.

**Confidential Internet Tokens**

Be careful when including claims in access tokens to not reveal sensitive data to internet clients, eg web or mobile apps. Aim to use the [phantom token pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/) if possible, so that you do not reveal any sensitive data. If the Authorization Server does not support issuing reference tokens, then option 2 above may be the least bad option.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. I believe, Option 2 is what we are looking for and probably you can look up the claims or roles from AD directly when the access token is received the first time and then cache them - similar to what you propose.